# Python: Find Amount of Handwriting in Video

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Do you know of an algorithm that can see **that there is handwriting** on an image? I am not interested in knowing what the handwriting says, but only that there is one present?

I have a video of someone filling a slide with handwriting. My goal is to determine how much of the slide has been filled with handwriting already.

[image]

The video in question can be downloaded here: http://www.filedropper.com/00_6

For this particular video, a great solution was already suggested in [Quantify how much a slide has been filled with handwriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63624333/quantify-how-much-a-slide-has-been-filled-with-handwriting/63644743?noredirect=1#comment112547543_63644743)

The solution is based on summing the amount of the specific color used for the handwriting. However, if the handwriting is not in blue but any other color that can also be found on non-handwriting, this approach will not work.

Therefore, **I am interested to know, if there exists a more general solution to determine if there is handwriting present on an image?**

*What I have done so far:*
I was thinking of extracting the contours of an image, and then somehow detect the handwriting part based on how curvy the contours are (but I have no clue how to do that part). it might not be the best idea, though, as again it's not always correct...

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



img = cv2.imread(PATH TO IMAGE)
print("img shape=", img.shape)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.imshow("image", gray)
cv2.waitKey(1)
#### extract all contours
# Find Canny edges 
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200) 
cv2.waitKey(0) 
  
# Finding Contours 
# Use a copy of the image e.g. edged.copy() 
# since findContours alters the image 
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged,  
    cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 
  
cv2.imshow('Canny Edges After Contouring', edged) 
cv2.waitKey(0) 
  
print("Number of Contours found = " + str(len(contours))) 
  
# Draw all contours 
# -1 signifies drawing all contours 
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3) 
  
cv2.imshow('Contours', img) 
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: The color of the handwritten text is different (blue vs black) so this seems pretty easy. I understand you noted it not being blue, but you could also have not black as what you're looking for.

Comment: @hrokr Thanks for your comment. To clarify: The color of the handwriting could be anything. Hence this will not help much for my case.

Comment: You can do this with something like OpenCV but the computational requirements are pretty substantial. And since it's good practice for educators to make notes in a different color, I think being pretty sure would be worth it. Are there any cases where both the notes and printed text are the same color or are you trying to plan for a more robust (if rare and computationally expensive) solution?

Comment: @hrokr Yes to both! Actually I do have videos where the educator uses black color as ink or adds object of the same color as the ink in the video. Therefore, I am planning for a more robust method.

Comment: OK, so that's helpful but a constraint like that would be good to know up front. Are there any other constraints you can think of? For example, always math? Are there marked transitions between slides?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220822/discussion-between-hrokr-and-henry).

Comment: Is it always the same background?...or is it possible to have a template of the screen without any hands and/or written text prior to when the video starts? If so you could subtract the template from the current frame and the result will be the written text.

Comment: @kavko very good question and suggestion. Unfortunately, the background is not always the same, though it usually does not change for one scene. By a scene, I mean all the frames in the video in which the slide does not change, but he is simply writing on it. If you watch the video, you will notice that there are 3 such scenes. What one might be able to do is to use the first frame of each scene as a background... what do you think?

Comment: If the first frame would be empty (like a template) then that would be possible and quite simple to implement. But in the video you posted there already is something written (plus the hand that is writing) on the first frame - which would make this task not so trivial. I asked the question because I didn't know if the video has been shortened for easier distribution. Have you looked at OpenCV's cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2() function - could be useful in this case.

Answer (score 9):

You can identify the space taken by hand-writing by masking the pixels from the template, and then do the same for the difference between further frames and the template. You can use dilation, opening, and thresholding for this.

Let's start with your [template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCj1d.jpg). Let's identify the parts we will mask:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

template = cv2.imread('template.jpg')
```

[image]

Now, let's broaden the occupied pixels to make a zone that we will mask (hide) later:

```
template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernel = np.ones((5, 5),np.uint8)
dilation = cv2.dilate(255 - template, kernel,iterations = 5)
```

[image]
Then, we will threshold to turn this into a black and white mask:

```
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(dilation,25,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

[image]

In later frames, we will subtract this mask from the picture, by turning all these pixels to white. For instance:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('0_0.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
frames = []

while count < 500:
  frames.append(image)
  success,image = vidcap.read()
  count += 1

mask = np.where(thresh == 0)

example = frames[300]
example[mask] = [255, 255, 255]
cv2.imshow('', example)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Now, we will create a function that will return the difference between the template and a given picture. We will also use opening to get rid of the left over single pixels that would make it ugly.

```
def difference_with_mask(image):
    grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
    dilation = cv2.dilate(255 - grayscale, kernel, iterations=5)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(dilation, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    thresh[mask] = 255
    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    return closing

cv2.imshow('', difference_with_mask(frames[400]))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

To address the fact that you don't want to have the hand detected as hand-writing, I suggest that instead of using the mask for every individual frame, you use the 95th percentile of the 15 last 30th frame... hang on. Look at this:

```
results = []
for ix, frame in enumerate(frames):
    if ix % 30 == 0:
        history.append(frame)
    results.append(np.quantile(history, 0.95, axis=0))
    print(ix)
```

Now, the example frame becomes this (the hand is removed because it wasn't mostly present in the 15 last 30th frames):

[image]

**As you can see a little part of the hand-writing is missing. It will come later, because of the time-dependent percentile transformation we're doing. You'll see later: in my example with frame 18,400, the text that is missing in the image above is present.** Then, you can use the function I gave you and this will be the result:

[image]

And here we go! Note that this solution, which doesn't include the hand, will take longer to compute because there's a few calculations needing to be done. Using just an image with no regard to the hand would calculate instantly, to the extent that you could probably run it on your webcam feed in real time.

**Final Example:**

Here's the frame 18,400:

[image]

Final image:

[image]

You can play with the function if you want the mask to wrap more thinly around the text:

[image]

**Full code:**

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('0_0.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
from collections import deque
frames = deque(maxlen=700)

while count < 500:
  frames.append(image)
  success,image = vidcap.read()
  count += 1

template = cv2.imread('template.jpg')
template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernel = np.ones((5, 5),np.uint8)
dilation = cv2.dilate(255 - template, kernel,iterations = 5)

cv2.imwrite('dilation.jpg', dilation)
cv2.imshow('', dilation)
cv2.waitKey(0)

_, thresh = cv2.threshold(dilation,25,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imwrite('thresh.jpg', thresh)
cv2.imshow('', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)

mask = np.where(thresh == 0)

example = frames[400]
cv2.imwrite('original.jpg', example)
cv2.imshow('', example)
cv2.waitKey(0)

example[mask] = 255
cv2.imwrite('example_masked.jpg', example)
cv2.imshow('', example)
cv2.waitKey(0)

def difference_with_mask(image):
    grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
    dilation = cv2.dilate(255 - grayscale, kernel, iterations=5)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(dilation, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    thresh[mask] = 255
    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    return closing


cv2.imshow('', difference_with_mask(frames[400]))
cv2.waitKey(0)

masked_example = difference_with_mask(frames[400])
cv2.imwrite('masked_example.jpg', masked_example)

from collections import deque
history = deque(maxlen=15)

results = []
for ix, frame in enumerate(frames):
    if ix % 30 == 0:
        history.append(frame)
    results.append(np.quantile(history, 0.95, axis=0))
    print(ix)
    if ix > 500:
        break


cv2.imshow('', frames[400])
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imshow('', results[400].astype(np.uint8))
cv2.imwrite('percentiled_frame.jpg', results[400].astype(np.uint8))
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imshow('', difference_with_mask(results[400].astype(np.uint8)))
cv2.imwrite('final.jpg', difference_with_mask(results[400].astype(np.uint8)))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try to make a template before detection which you could use to deduct it on the current frame of the video. One way you could make such a template is to iterate through every pixel of the frame and look-up if it has a higher value (white) in that coordinate than the value that is stored in the list.

Here is an example of such a template from your video by iterating through the first two seconds:

[image]

Once you have that it is simple to detect the text. You can use the `cv2.absdiff()` function to make difference of template and frame. Here is an example:

[image]

Once you have this image it is trivial to search for writting (threshold + contour search or something similar).

Here is an example code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('0_0.mp4')  # read video

bgr = cap.read()[1]  # get first frame
frame = cv2.cvtColor(bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # transform to grayscale
template = frame.copy()  # make a copy of the grayscale

h, w = frame.shape[:2]  # height, width

matrix = []  # a list for [y, x] coordinares
# fill matrix with all coordinates of the image (height x width)
for j in range(h):
    for i in range(w):
        matrix.append([j, i])

fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)  # frames per second of the video
seconds = 2  # How many seconds of the video you wish to look the template for
k = seconds * fps  # calculate how many frames of the video is in that many seconds
i = 0  # some iterator to count the frames
lowest = []  # list that will store highest values of each pixel on the fram - that will build our template

# store the value of the first frame - just so you can compare it in the next step
for j in matrix:
    y = j[0]
    x = j[1]
    lowest.append(template[y, x])

# loop through the number of frames calculated before
while(i < k):
    bgr = cap.read()[1]  # bgr image
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # transform to grayscale
    # iterate through every pixel (pixels are located in the matrix)
    for l, j in enumerate(matrix):
        y = j[0]  # x coordinate
        x = j[1]  # y coordinate
        temp = template[y, x]  # value of pixel in template
        cur = frame[y, x]  # value of pixel in the current frame
        if cur > temp:  # if the current frame has higher value change the value in the "lowest" list
            lowest[l] = cur
    i += 1  # increment the iterator

    # just for vizualization
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

i = 0  # new iteratir to increment position in the "lowest" list
template = np.ones((h, w), dtype=np.uint8)*255  #  new empty white image
# iterate through the matrix and change the value of the new empty white image to that value
# in the "lowest" list
for j in matrix:
    template[j[0], j[1]] = lowest[i]
    i += 1

# just for visualization - template
cv2.imwrite("template.png", template)
cv2.imshow("template", template)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

counter = 0  # counter of countours: logicaly if the number of countours would
# rapidly decrease than that means that a new template is in order
mean_compare = 0  # this is needed for a simple color checker if the contour is
# the same color as the oders
# this is the difference between the frame of the video and created template
while(cap.isOpened()):
    bgr = cap.read()[1]  # bgr image
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # grayscale
    img = cv2.absdiff(template, frame)  # resulted difference
    thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]  # thresholded image
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), dtype=np.uint8)  # simple kernel
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)  # dilate thresholded image
    cnts, h = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)  # contour search
    if len(cnts) < counter*0.5 and counter > 50:  # check if new template is in order
        # search for new template again
        break
    else:
        counter = len(cnts) # update counter
        for cnt in cnts:  # iterate through contours
            size = cv2.contourArea(cnt)  # size of contours - to filter out noise
            if 20 < size < 30000:  # noise criterion
                mask = np.zeros(frame.shape, np.uint8)  # empry mask - needed for color compare
                cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], -1, 255, -1)  # draw contour on mask
                mean = cv2.mean(bgr, mask=mask)  # the mean color of the contour

                if not mean_compare:  # first will set the template color
                    mean_compare = mean
                else:
                    k1 = 0.85  # koeficient how much each channels value in rgb image can be smaller
                    k2 = 1.15 # koeficient how much each channels value in rgb image can be bigger
                    # condition
                    b = bool(mean_compare[0] * k1 < mean[0] < mean_compare[0] * k2)
                    g = bool(mean_compare[1] * k1 < mean[1] < mean_compare[1] * k2)
                    r = bool(mean_compare[2] * k1 < mean[2] < mean_compare[2] * k2)
                    if b and g and r:
                        cv2.drawContours(bgr, [cnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)  # draw on rgb image

    # just for visualization
    cv2.imshow('img', bgr)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('s'):
        cv2.imwrite(str(j)+".png", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# release the video object and destroy window
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

One possible result with a simple size and color filter:

[image]

NOTE: This template search algorithm is very slow because of the nested loops and can probably be optimized to make it faster - you need a little more math knowledge than me. Also, you will need to make a check if the template changes in the same video - I'm guessing that shouldn't be too difficult.

A simpler idea on how to make it a bit faster is to resize the frames to let's say 20% and make the same template search. After that resize it back to the original and dilate the template. It will not be as nice of a result but it will make a mask on where the text and lines of the template are. Then simply draw it over the frame.

Comment: +1 That's very impressive! A question: You write in the beginning "that is stored in the list.", what "list" do you mean? Many thanks!

Comment: You can create a list of values by itterating through the first frame and store those values (grayscale images have values 0-black to 255-white) in some list. Then compare those values with the values of the next frame - when the hand moves out of the picture, those values will be higher (255 - white) - you replace them with the highest one and you can make a "template". I hope I made it a bit more clear

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really need the code in this case and it would be rather long if you did. But here's an algorithm to do it.

Use OpenCV's EAST (Efficient Accurate Scene Text detector) model at the beginning to establish the starting text on the slide. That gives you a bounding box(es) of the initial percentage of the slide covered with slide text as opposed to handwritten explanatory text.

Every, say 1-5 seconds (people don't write all that fast), compare that baseline image with the current image and the previous image.

- If the current image has more text than the previous image but the initial bounding boxes are NOT the same, you have a new and rather busy slide.
- If the current image has more text than the previous image but the initial bounding boxes are ARE the same, more text is being added.
- If the current image had less text than the previous image but the initial bounding boxes are NOT the same, you again have a new slide -- only, not busy and with space like the last one to write.
- If the current image has less text than the previous image but the initial bounding boxes are ARE the same, you either have a duplicate slide with what will presumably be more text or the teacher is erasing a section to continue, or modify their explanation. Meaning, you'll need some way of addressing this.

When you have a new slide, take the previous image, and compare the bounding boxes of all text, subtracting the boxes for the initial state.

Computationally, this isn't going to be cheap (you certainly won't be doing this life, at least not for a number of years) but it's robust, and sampling the text every so many seconds of time will help.

Personally, I would approach this as an ensemble. That is an initial bounding box then look at the color of the text. If you *can* get away with the percentage of different color text, do. And when you can't, you'll still be good.

Comment: It’s a good idea, but what if he just adds more non-handwritten text, like animated bullet points that appear one after the other onto the slide? Your answer is very similar to my approach in this other question I had: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63624333/quantify-how-much-a-slide-has-been-filled-with-handwriting

Comment: Basically, you don’t even need to detect a text, you can also just look at how much was added to each frame comparing to the previous frame. However, I’m really interested in knowing, if there is hand-writing on the frame, yes or no, and then if yes, how much compared to the previous?

Comment: Ok, in the comment section of the question, you said: *"Sometimes, it’s even a drawing, but I guess this will make it just even more complicated, So forget about that for now."* But here you're saying, essentially: *"But what about this edge case that wasn't disclosed and which I've also said not to worry about?"*  It can't be P and ~P at the same time. What set of constraints and requirements would get you to a good MVP or better?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the great answers that people provided, I have two other suggestions.

The first one, is the CNN methods. It's totally workable to use some object detection routine, or even a segmentation method (like U-NET) to differentiate between the texts. It is easy because you can find millions of images from digital text books and also handwritten documents to train your model.

The Second approach is to locate and to extract every single symbol on the image, separately (with a simple method like the one you used so far, or with `connectedcomponent`). Since typographic letters and symbols have a unique shape and style (similar fonts - unlike the handwritten letters) you can match all the found letters with sample typographic letters that you gathered separately to distinguish between the handwritten and the typographic. Feature-point-based matching (like SURF) could be a good tool for this approach.